# JPA LocalDateTime comparison SQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a Java project which contains an entity with a LocalDateTime. I want to extract records via SQL where the LocalDateTime falls in between 2 other LocalDateTime's.

**ENTITY**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false)
private long id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false)   
private long assignmentId;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false)   
private LocalDateTime startDateTime;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false)   
private LocalDateTime endDateTime;
```

**JAVA**

```
//Sub assignments
public List<Subassignment> findAllSubassignmentsForAssignmentBetweenDates(long id, LocalDateTime startDateTime, LocalDateTime endDateTime) {
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("ResourceVO.findByAssignmentIdAndDates", Subassignment.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .setParameter("sdt", startDateTime)
            .setParameter("edt", endDateTime)
            .getResultList();
}
```

**QUERY**

```
<named-query name='ResourceVO.findByAssignmentIdAndDates'>
    <query>         
        SELECT c FROM Subassignment AS c 
        WHERE (c.assignmentId IN (SELECT b.id FROM Assignment b WHERE b.resource.id = :id))
        AND (c.startDateTime BETWEEN :sdt AND :edt)

    </query>
</named-query>
```

I'm always getting an 'Internal Server Error'. Any tips or suggestions?

P.S. The query works fine without the LocalDateTime parameters.

Thanks

Matthijs

Comment: any exception has a stack trace, and a root cause. Any query is either failing before execution, or failing with execution, in which case it would log the SQL invoked ...

Comment: You can´t just use LocalDateTime in a SQL Querry. You will have to convert it to java.sql.date in order to make it work. Maybe a normal date would work as well but I´m not sure there.

Comment: But will I be able to compare them to the LocalDateTime's?

Comment: why not provide the basic debugging information and then you can see clearer where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed LocalDateTime to long